# Does Flash object require minimum width/height to initialize?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

I just noticed that in legacy browsers (like IE 6,7,8, FF 3.6) Flash doesn't initialize if size of the object is less then 9x9 px. I do not remember myself ever encountering this problem in the past, when those dinosaurs dominated the web. Do you?

What is that size? And can you share a link to a resource that goes deeper in this topic?

**UPDATE:** I just checked and Silverlight doesn't seem to have such problem.

Comment: What was that size? In fact I've been working quite intensively with 1x1 px flash objects used as shims for various operations and do not remember any such thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use camera, you flash object needs to be at least 215x138, in every browser. I remember there was a minimum size in IE but cant find a source. Anyway, maybe this info helps; You can make a transparent Flash object using `wmode="transparent"`. You cannot use `display:none` or `visibility` (css) because then the flash isn't executed or acts slower. To make sure it keeps running, place it `position:fixed` (css) on the page in a corner or something. Browsers make flash object run in a sort of sleep mode (slower) when out of screen or when inactive (ie in an inactive tab)

I think thats a way to make a shim with an swf. its position matters.

Btw, I would not suggest to use silverlight, it has low penetration.

Source minimum window size with camera:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html

Comment: I think this happens due to some recent addition to Flash player. 'cause it definitely didn't happen with Flash Player 9 or even 10.